Creating a directx user control to be used in a UWP xaml application
I'm trying to add some directx functionality to a large vb .net UWP xaml islands project. Looks like the best approach is to make a c++ windows runtime component with the directx logic and use it from the vb project.
I am starting with the project template Directx 11 and Xaml app - it works fine.
I create a new solution with a blank c++app xaml project and a windows runtime component project with a very simple user control. I can register the wrc from the xaml app and display the simple user control, works fine.
I create another user control ucThreed, copy all the code from the first attempt and basically make the user control do the same as the blank page in the original directx template. Everything builds fine and I can put a ucThreed user control on my page in the c++ xaml app.
But when I run, I get "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF7A70CD29 in cppgui.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x000000720986DC10. HRESULT:0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
WinRT information: The system cannot find the file specified."
Have I made an obvious mistake or are there better examples of how to do this? Thanks

You don't need C++, for example see a similar SwapChainPanel-based .NET (C#) project for WinUI3 https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/tree/master/DirectN/DirectN.WinUI3.MinimalD3D11 otherwise please post a real sample, we can't guess what's your problem w/o a simple reproducing project How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Thanks, I am looking at your suggestions, I would like to avoid adding any third party components if possible and the project template Directx 11 and Xaml app seems to do it quite well. My steps to reproduce are as above, I appreciate it would take some time to do this though, all I can do otherwise is provide my entire solution.  Really I would like to start from  the c++ Directx 11 and Xaml app template with the minimum steps to make it work as a user control from another project.

As I said you should post a reproducible project if you seek for any help

Ok I uploaded my solution to http://belchamber.net/wrc2.zip It has ThreeD, a windows runtime component, which has SimpleUserControl (which works in both of the gui projects) and ucThreed which does not. ucThreeD is a user control built exactly the same as the Main Page in the default project template for directx and xaml.

Ok found what I was looking for, simple example of working directx with c#: https://github.com/stammen/uwp-cpp-examples/tree/master/XAML%20SwapChainPanel%20DirectX%20interop%20sample

was missing the www , in case it is of interest, http://www.belchamber.net/wrc2.zip

still doesn't work

This did it for me, nice directx project providing a Xaml D3DPanel which can be used in a simple c# or vb gui project: https://github.com/stammen/uwp-cpp-examples/tree/master/XAML%20SwapChainPanel%20DirectX%20interop%20sample
My links to my attempt which did not work do not seem to work when clicked on but do if you copy / paste the url

It is appreciated to share your solution here. Please don't forget to accept your answer since the solution works for you.
